# Mysql select . php

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT id_prod
FROM  `ordered_products` 
WHERE id_order =10
```

результатом является набор чисел 1 2 3 4
то есть id_prod из разных  строк,где id_order=10;
как вывести такой массив в php?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_prod
FROM  `ordered_products` 
WHERE id_order = 10");
$my =  mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Недавно узнал про такую функцию GROUP_CONCAT().

Вот запрос

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT id_prod SEPARATOR ',' ) as id_prod
FROM ordered_products
WHERE id_order=10
```

запрос вернет 1 строку, в которой через запятую будут перечислены все id_prod.
DISTINCT - уберет из заказа дублирующие продукты.

Для преобразования результата в массив - просто

```
$arr_prod=explode(',',$row['id_prod']);
```

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump($my)` или `print_r($my)` функции, наверное, если я правильно понял вопрос. Или через foreach перебрать.

Вот какой пример на php.net:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Имя: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);
}
```

Comment: Но так print_r выдает Array ( [0] => 1 [id_prod] => 1), то есть только первую строчку.

Comment: Попробуйте 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Имя: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);
}